# Best Reporting Tool for Java Swing

Tags: java, jasper-reports, reporting, birt

Hello there guy's and gal's

I was looking for a reporting tool that suit for Eclipse IDE, easy to use, and free.
I already know a little in BIRT Reporting in Eclipse but the only problem is BIRT Report consume a lot of memory upon execution.

While go ogling, Jasper's report caught my attention because of its availability but suddenly integrating jasper report to my swing application didn't go well, I've been stuck for almost 2-weeks until I ended in using BIRT report. because no one cares to help me out...

but here i am again still looking for a good reporting tool that i can perfectly integrate to my swing application under the Eclipse IDE

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever ask a question here about your problems with Jasper Reports? I do not see any listed in your profile? Also you should take a look at [What is the best report Engine for Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238527/what-is-the-best-report-engine-for-java) as it is exactly the question you are asking.

Comment: What you means with "perfectly integrate to my swing application"?

Comment: @jschoen 
I'm new here at STACKOVERFLOW that's why I'd never ask that's why I have to work on my own problem without asking the others, but when I register to this site, I found that most of the guru's here don't troll the newbie like me.

That's why I try to ask again my unfinished business regarding jasper report.  

Anyways, thanks  to you guys from STACKOVERFLOW for guiding me.

Comment: @Horcrux7 I'm having trouble integrating jasper report to my swing application, even if i had a ebook as a guide still got an error regarding driver.. I used Eclipse IDE and some people says Jasper is design for Netbeans so i ended in using BIRT Report.

Thanks for your response.

Comment: I would like to mention [jCharts](http://jcharts.sourceforge.net/) for reporting tool in Swing applications. Couldn't answer the closed question(so adding this as a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use iText to generate PDF output from our Java applications.

http://itextpdf.com/

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-javapdf/

Comment: Is it applicable to connect to mysql database?

Comment: is there a gui designer tool for this sir?

Comment: @Alvin: Your Java code would have to connect to MySQL.  iText is a reporting tool.

Comment: @Alvin: iText comes with a simple GUI: the iText toolbox.  Most of our reports have the same headers and footers, so we just have to produce the report itself.

Comment: got it sir, thanks for your response i'd really appreciate it.